# Automating a webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, coding-style

I want to perform certain actions on a existing webpage in loop

1. clicking on side menu bar.
2. clicking the filter option.
3. selecting a certain link opening the link.
4. going to the next page.
5. changing the options in dropdown of the opened link.
6. Clicking on a certain button.
   How can I perform this action using coding ? Which language is preferable if I am already using selenium?

Comment: Hello Shreya Shubhangi and welcome to Stack Overlow. Right now it is hard to understand what your answer is, you could only guess. Please edit your question to clarify your problem and add a minimal example of your code that creates that problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so you can rephrase your question.

Comment: Why do you want to use another 'language'? Is there a problem with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will do all of this for you, and a whole lot more!  Below is an example using Firefox; you can easily use Chrome, IE, etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Utility/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)


url = "https://www.google.com/"
wd.get(url)


# download geckodriver for windows 64-bit from here
# https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

You will need to focus on things like this:

```
 find_element_by_class_name(name)

    Finds an element by class name.
    Args:   
        name: The class name of the element to find.

    Returns:    
        WebElement - the element if it was found

    Raises: 
        NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn’t found

    Usage:  
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('foo')
```

See the links below for more info.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/